# c# xml loaded in datagridview, how to add new row with datas from texboxes (clicking a button)?

Tags: c#, xml, button, datagridview, row

Error : The input table is longer than the number of columns in this table.

Thanks for your help

The button code : c#

```
private void ADDROW_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)  
{
DataSet objDs = new DataSet(); 
DataTable objDt = new DataTable();
objDt.Rows.Add(T01.Text,T02.Text,T03.Text,T04.Text);
objDs.ReadXml("s.xml"); 
objDs.Tables.Add(objDt); 
dataGridView1.DataSource = objDs.Tables[0]; 
}
```

The xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <ta>
    <Genre>Red</Genre>
    <Nom>Val</Nom>
    <Note>8</Note>
    <Vue>2023</Vue>
  </ta>
  <ta>
    <Genre>Blue</Genre>
    <Nom>Col</Nom>
    <Note>2</Note>
    <Vue>2022</Vue>
  </ta>
  ...
 </NewDataSet>
```

I don t know how to do, starting code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the columns first.

```
private void ADDROW_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
    DataTable objDt;
    DataRow objRw;

    if (dataGridView1.DataSource == null)
    {
        objDt = new DataTable("ta");
        objDt.Columns.Add("Genre");
        objDt.Columns.Add("Nom");
        objDt.Columns.Add("Note");
        objDt.Columns.Add("Vue");
    }
    else
    {
        objDt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
    }

    objRw = objDt.NewRow();
    objRw["Genre"] = T01.Text;
    objRw["Nom"] = T02.Text;
    objRw["Note"] = T03.Text;
    objRw["Vue"] = T04.Text;
    objDt.Rows.Add(objRw);

    if (dataGridView1.DataSource == null)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = objDt;
    }
}

private void READXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
    DataSet objDs = new DataSet();
    objDs.ReadXml("s.xml")
    dataGridView1.DataSource = objDs.Tables[0]; 
}
```